# Reset inherited WPF style?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-style

In the App.xaml portion of my application I have a `ResourceDictionary` element that targets things like `DataGridColumnHeader` and `DataGridCell` and applies custom styling to them. These definitions are global (in that they don't use a x:key - they apply to all instances of the type).

Is it possible to completely reset the style of these types to the 'base' Aero theme (or whatever theme is currently in use) for use in a subsection of my application?

I've tried using

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
    </Style>
```

Which doesn't seem to do anything, as I'm guessing its just inheriting itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 2 ways to reset the style:

1. Set the style property of the element to `{x:Null}`. You will have to do this on every element.

   ```
   <Button Height="50" Style="{x:Null}"></Button>
   ```
2. Define an empty style in the resources of the element containing the elements you want to reset. Don't specify `BasedOn`, otherwise it will inherit all properties and does not reset them to standard (as you correctly noticed).

   ```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
   </Style>
   ```

Comment: The null trick also seems to work for BasedOn, that is you can do something like: `<Style TargetType="..." BasedOn="{x:Null}"` to reset to the default WPF style.